# Is one allowed to fly a "Yiddish" Kite on Shabbat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A "Yiddish" kite is a special kite that is shaped like a huge piece of kishke and has the words, "Ah Gitten Shabbess" (In Yiddish) on it. Assuming that there is an Eruv, would one be allowed to fly the Yiddish kite on Shabbess?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: where can I procure such a cool kite

Comment: @Nafkamina - At Tchatkes Zeinin Unz in Williamsburg. They also carry narrish kites!

Comment: A kite shaped like kishke is not a Yiddish kite but a miess kite.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, one may ONLY fly it on Shabbos -- one may not even take it down from flying until after the day is over. Ma'alin bakodesh, v'ein moridin.

Comment: I disagree I think limiting it only to shabbos smacks of too much frum -kite

Answer (score 4):

As you know in Yiddish-kite nothing is simple. First there are those who hold of the Eruv and there are those that do not. Then there is a question of Eidel-kite. Is it Eidel to fly a kite? Then there is a question of Kishke as it brings some to a stomach Krank-kite. Thus the best thing to do in such a situation is to ask a non Jew to do a Shain-kite and please fly the kite until Shabbos is over.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you must say the words "Nicht on Shabbos Geredt" before flying it.

Answer (score 0):

For a man, any type of kite flying is assur gamur, irrespective of it's similarity in appearance to a shabbos kishke. If, however, it is orange like said kishke, please consider consulting a doctor.

For the uninformed: "flying a kite" is a... Particular euphemism...